# Graph Theory: Clique concepts

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, clique, clique-problem

I was trying to solve a basic clique problem but i have stucked at some following points:

- `what is is the minimum size of the largest clique in any graph with N nodes and M edges`
- `To Find the largest clique in a graph`

Please tell me difference between above two statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a question about the set of all graphs with `N` nodes and `M` edges. The second question appears to be about a particular graph (although it seems to be out of context).

It might be better to ask this on https://math.stackexchange.com/